# How do I code to keep 8 threads active in my program at all times?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

My code has to process a few hundred files independently. I would like to keep my program processing 8 threads all the time. Once one of the thread completes, I would like to launch a new thread processing a new file without blocking my code for all threads to complete until the very end.

I am using pthread on linux.

I have no clue on how to code this. does `pthread_join()` block code execution? How do I know when one thread is completed? How does this code execute?

```
pthread_join(thread1)
pthread_join(thread2)
```

Does thread1 have to finish before `pthread_join(thread2)` executes?

So, if I place

```
for (i=0;i<7;i++)
    pthread_join(thread[i])
cout<<"Here!";
```

Does it mean that I have to wait for all threads to finish before `Here!` is printed?

Or should I not use pthreads at all?

Comment: Look up the concept of a thread pool and job queue. Boost will have some high level constructs that will help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a cost in creating a new thread and there's no reason to have to spawn a new thread for every file. In addition, there's extra work to be done tracking these threads so you could join them if needed.

A better approach would be to have a single synchronized queue. The main thread will insert jobs (for example, paths) and your working threads could read from the queue and process each file. The worker threads will block until a job is inserted into the queue.

If you don't have access to a synchronized queue, creating one should be rather easy by using mutex locks on the operations.

pthread_join indeed blocks until the provided thread completes. So in your example, all threads would have to be completed for the print to take place.

If you really want to spawn a new thread every time one dies - you could call some function just before returning from the function your thread executes. This function will spawn a new thread which will process the next file. When all files will be processed, the threads number will automatically decrease.

Answer (score 2):

> does `pthread_join()` block code execution?

Yes, it specifically waits for the joined thread to finish executing, and returns its exit code. So, the calling thread will block until this happens.

You'll notice that the [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) is very explicit about this:

> *The `pthread_join()` function shall suspend execution of the calling thread until the target thread terminates*

---

As Vadim says, the correct approach is generally to have one long-lived thread per core, and  dispatch work to your threads/cores using a queue or something similar. Stopping and starting threads all the time is inefficient.

In other words, a thread *is not a task*. A thread executes tasks one after another.

Note that whether your filesystem can really keep 8 concurrent threads busy will depend on what you're doing: file accesses will probably be serialized through the driver anyway, and if you end up limited by I/O rather than CPU, many threads may not be the most efficient approach.

Comment: I have to read a file and then spend time processing it. The files are images. So I am assuming that the time to process them is not so insignificant compared to disk access time.

Comment: In this case, the threading model described is probably fine.

Answer (score 1):

Pardon my ignorance, but I see no benefit in having more than one thread for reading the files.

**Device I/O bottleneck**
Unless your computer has a separate I/O channel for each hard disk and each file is on a separate disk, one of your performance bottleneck is the I/O channel.  Most computers can only read one channel at a time or maybe multiplex messages to the hard drive for multiple channels.

**Drive seek position**
In an ideal situation where one file is a contiguous set of sectors, you will have two seek operations: directory lookup and file opening.  The drive would deliver all the data without having to reposition the head.

When you read multiple files simultaneous on a single hard drive, the hard drive has to seek to one file, read some data, seek to the second file, read some data and so on until it cycles around to the first file.  There is a minimum of one seek operation per file, for each block of data read.  Thus accumulating to a huge amount of time seeking to various places in the hard disk.

**Multiple cores one I/O channel**
Internally, the data has to come from the hard drive into the PC's memory.  Then the appropriate core has to use the single databus or single memory region to fetch its data.  Imagine a single lane of road with traffic signals.  Each core will be blocked (waiting) until the databus (road) is available.  Thus more wait time.

**Thread switching overhead**
There is a cost associated with threads:  creation and switching.  Even with a ratio of one thread per processor, the OS must coordinate and manage the threads.  Essentially, each thread adds a bookkeeping cost which subtracts from the performance and memory space of your program.

**One I/O thread, multiple processing threads.**
The goal in high performance with files is to keep the hard drive spinning and reduce the number of seek operations.  On thread could easily accomplish this.

Allocating one buffer for each processing thread would aid in performance.  The file reading thread would fill one buffer for a processing thread and move on to the next.  Systems with multiple processors or cores have data bus sharing optimized; so each core spends the least amount of time being blocked.

**Core Caches**
The processing threads should fetch as much data from the I/O buffer into the processor's data cache as possible.  This allows one core to be processing data from its cache while another core is loading its cache from the I/O buffer.

**Physical Optimizations**
Some university experiments have shown large performance increases by making physical changes to the system.  One example is to use one hard drive for each data bit.  Other systems use many hard drives and distribute the files across many hard drives to alleviate the demand on a single drive.  Some systems actually have more than one I/O channel to memory.  Direct Memory Access (DMA) controllers can fetch data from an I/O port into memory while the processor does other things.

**Summary**
I recommend optimizing using one read thread first before expanding to multiple read threads.  Processing the data may benefit from additional threads.  You'll get more noticeable performance improvement by optimizing your threads for use of CPU data caches and instruction pipelines.

Comment: Each thread is supposed to read from disk and process. I understand that the threads shall hold up during read from the same disk, but the processing shall be parallelized. After reading the first 8 (MAX_THREADS=8) file reads, the threads shall be staggered and the the likelihood of threads blocking each other for disk access shall be less.